# Poppler win32: missing include

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qt5, poppler

I downloaded pre-built win32 poppler binaries from this [page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-win32/). But saw only the bin folder and not include/bin folders. I need a include folder (which must contains my poppler-qt5 folder) to put in my .pro file (i'm using qt5 to test).

My .pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\test_folder\\poppler-0.24.5-win32\\include\\poppler-qt5"
LIBS += -L/"C:\\test_folder\\poppler-0.24.5-win32\\lib"
```

My questions is: 
Where should I put the bin folder, is the include folder provided by the [release](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/)? Or should I put the include folder from this release inside poppler-win32 folder?